# Vectors and many indices

Tags: c++, containers

The situation: I am reading a 3D file format which is made up from geometry blocks. Each block in turn, has references (using indices), to any of the blocks (similar to potentially visible sets).

The program I am designing should allow to insert and delete blocks anywhere in the list. This means that a lot of the references will become invalid.

One workaround for this would be to convert the indices into pointers when reading the file, so to have a vector of pointers like this:

```
class block;

class block
{
    std::vector<block*> a_references;

    // more data
};

std::vector<block*> a_blocks;
```

In my program the user can view the referenced blocks for each block of the `a_blocks` array. Here, I want to display them as *indices*. When using pointers over indices, this means I will have to do an `std::find` for each block to find its index in the array. This will cause a lot of overhead I presume?

Which approach is better, and what are the performance benefits?

Comment: So the references are originally given in terms of indices. What is supposed to happen if a block at some  referenced index is removed? Should the invalid reference be preserved? What should happen if at the same index a new block is created? Does the old reference now point to this new block?

Comment: Is your issue that you can't find the index of your `block` in the array given only the `block*`? Why can't you just store the block's index within it? And update the indices when blocks are inserted/deleted?

Comment: @Nabla: When a block is removed, the references should be preserved but (preferably) be set to NULL, so that the user can adjust or remove them. When a new block is created at the same index, the references should still point to the old block.

Comment: @Midas With `old block` you mean old index, right? Because the old block was removed. And does order of references matter?

Comment: @Nable: New index, since the block has changed position in the list after a new block is inserted. And yes, the order matters, both for the list of blocks, and the lists with references.

Comment: @Midas Ah ok, I thought your vector would be fixed length, so that every block would always keep its index. If you actually want a linked list, you should use `list` instead of `vector`.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do (if I have correctly understood your question):
keep index:

```
class block
{
    std::vector<std::size_t> a_references; // some indices in a_blocks

    // more data
};

std::vector<block*> a_blocks;
```

Then instead of remove element, reset it to `nullptr`
Add element in hole or at the end of the vector.
Finally, you may have a function to collapse which remove holes and fixes index.

An alternative would be:

```
class block
{
    std::vector<block*> a_references;
    std::vector<block*> back_references; // reference each block where `this` is in a_reference 
    std::size_t index; // index in a_blocks 

    // more data
};
```

On deletion, you have a quick access to blocks which refer it.
On insertion/deletion, you have to update all index in linear time

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't solve the problem. When a block is deleted or inserted, the indices which are visible to the user should be updated to match the new list. The solution you gave assumes that the indices remain the same, because you don't remove them from the list. Also, I didn't understand the second option? What's the purpose of the additional variables? (...) I guess updating every index in every block manually (as Dave proposed) is the only way to go...

Comment: @Midas: For the second option `index` is as Dave propose, `back_reference` is the list of blocks to modify when the current block is deleted (if `a_references` are the blocks viewed, `back_reference` are the blocks which view current block).